# Automate hibernate in linux mint

Tags: linux, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

How can I do hibernate operation after some hours/minutes ? 
 That is I want something like this , `hibernate now + 3hour` to hibernate system after 3 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "at" command:

> at and batch read commands from standard input or a specified file
>   which are to be executed at a later time, using /bin/sh.

Example: echo 'touch test' | at now +1 minutes

Reference [at usage](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm)